# Meaning of size parameter in SSBO

Tags: opengl, size, buffer, shader

I use two SSBO's in a fragment shader. For each fragment, I make a calculation and, if some condition is met, I write the worldspace coordinates of the fragment/pixel (they have been passed on to the fragment shader) to one SSBO and the fragment color to the other one. The SSBO's are then read by the application and those pixels which have been kept in the SSBO's are passed on to the next rendering.

The size parameter in

```
void glBufferData( GLenum target, GLsizeiptr size, const GLvoid * data, GLenum usage);
```

can have two values for the moment: `2500` or `20000`.

For the passes where the `size = 2500`, everything works fine. As soon as `size = 20000`, then most pixels cease to be registered in the SSBO's.

My question: what is the actual meaning of the size parameter? Is it the size of what can be written in each fragment instanciation (in this case, it would be only one `vec4` per SSBO per fragment) or is it the size of all the instanciations in each rendering pass (in this case 2500 or 20000 `vec4` per SSBO)?

Comment: The size passed to `glBufferData()` is the size of the buffer in bytes. Not sure if your question has anything specifically to do with SSBOs, or just the basic function of `glBufferData()`.

Comment: `glBufferData` allocates and (if `data` is non-null) fills the buffer with initial data supplied to the call. If you are having trouble understanding what `size` means in this API call you are probably overrunning a buffer every time you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your SSBOs contain a `vec4`. 
Their size is their total size is byte (as Reto Koradi said) for one frame, it you reset it every time with `glBufferData`. A `vec4` is 16 bytes (4 bytes per `float`, they are 32 bit). So a size of 2500 means 2500/16 = 156(.25) vec4s. 20000 bytes is 1250 `vec4s`.

Comment: Thanks. You answer my question. I had come to think that I was misinterpreting the meaning of the size parameter. I see it as you and Koradi see it: it s the size of the full buffer for a complete frame. And, just to make everything clear, the size was either 20000 * sizeof(vec4) or 2500 * sizeof(vec4) and a vec4 is for 16 bytes.

Comment: I'm glad you understood !